# Trying to get property of non object is the error what iam getting in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display individual values passed from controller to view page but when i try to do so iam getting error has TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON OBJECT so request ci developers to help me

**This is my controller page**

```
 $data['showdata']  =   $this->searchresultss->login($per_page,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);
        $this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
**This is my view page**
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($showdata);
  if (isset($showdata)){
            foreach ($showdata as $key) {
?>
<?php echo($key->gender); ?>// This is the line where iam getting error
  <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
**Here is my model page**
<?php
Class Searchresultss extends CI_Model
{

 function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
 {


$query="SELECT *
FROM users
";

$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();

$data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3);

return $data;
 }
}
```

I am geting error has trying to get property of non object. I am trying to print individual values passed from controller to view page ..but I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You are not load the model in controler. Load the model `searchresultss` in controller before calling the model function. Like,

```
$this->load->model('searchresultss');
```

And

Change
 `echo($key->gender);`
To

```
echo $key['gender'];
```

This will solve the issue

Comment: @vicky Ok , I found the problem. Answer again edited. change echo($key->gender); to echo $key['gender'];

Answer (score 0):

your echo is not wrong.

but i guess you didnt take the result of your query so:

try this :

```
  if (isset($showdata)){
  foreach ($showdata->result() as $key){ // just add ->result() after $showdata
  echo($key->gender); ?>
  }
  }
```

Comment: try this:     if (isset($data['showdata'])){
              foreach ($data['showdata']->result() as $key) {
              echo ($key->gender);}}

Comment: in your model you returned the result or no like this: return $data->result();

Comment: so just clean ->result() and try again. sorry but it was better if you puted your model function as well

Comment: hey for make sure please before you send $data to view just put this and see what will happen:   if (isset($data['showdata'])){
            foreach ($data['showdata']->result() as $key) {

 echo ($key->gender);
  
            }
        }exit;

Comment: sorry but need to your model function as well

Comment: function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
 {
  

$query="select * from users";

$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();
//$data['pages']=ceil($count/$per_page);
$data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3);

return $data;
 }

Comment: help me out in solving